# Remove suggested-edits notification

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I find it distracting, so I decided to try get rid of it by doing 20 reviews, but it kept coming back. It should be enough that **review** is visible on every page right?

[image]

It says there are 6 reviews pending in the image above.

Comment: Can you explain what this is? When do you get the notification, what does it say, etc.?

Comment: I was actually about to suggest the same thing. It is quite annoying that it shows up even after 20 edit reviews

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think he's talking about the pending edit indicator in the topbar.

Comment: I find it more useful then distracting. It actually informs you when there is something to review. Otherwise, you would have to check the review section manually and depending on the queue possibly find nothing to review (except for close votes - never shortage there).

Comment: @JoshMein after having reviewed 20 edits there is nothing more to review, since the `thanks for having reviewed 20 edits` screen shows up.

Comment: @dontfuxx I did not realize the suggested edits max review per day was only 20. I frequent Close Votes queue which is 40 per day. The OP needs to indicate that he has used up all of his reviews for the day because it is not clear that he wants it removed after they have been used up.

Comment: @JoshMein It's 2 problems: I don't like it, but it's worse that it does not even go away when I've run out of my 20 reviews.

Comment: I doubt they will get rid of it considering I have seen several requests to add more features like this. However, I agree that it should disappear once you have used up your votes for the day. You never know though, the SE team could create an option for you to disable such notifications. Please update your question to make your insight more clear and what you would like them to do.

Comment: @michaelb958 not quite. I just want to see the orange blob gone.

Comment: @Tshepang The dupe target is more-or-less about getting rid of the blob, and many other questions like this one have been marked as a duplicate of it. How "not quite"?

Comment: @michaelb958 I do not want it to appear even though I haven't reached my 20 reviews.

Comment: @Tshepang Ah, I get it. I suspect it's by design in that circumstance, though.